# Apex Batch slow

Tags: apex, batch, performance

I've launched an apex batch but each processed batch is too slow. Looking at the duration of each execute method, I see that the duration is around 2.668 ms but the next execute method is processed after one minute. 
Where could be the problem? I usually launch this batch every week and I never faced this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320538&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1), Salesforce provides no SLA for asynchronous processing. Your org runs on a multi-tenanted server, so it is likely that the server is experiencing a larger than normal load due to the other tenants and/or due to more users performing synchronous activities. You may also have added more future method invocations (or similar) to your code base that might be saturating your async queue.